# Rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am bit confused of react rendering Logic.
Here are the two ways in which we can write the the code for JSX.
First to write entire HTML and second to break html to smaller functions that returns the HTML

I would like know which way one should procceed in terms of Component performance and code readability?

First one is

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div class="user"> {... } </div>
                <div class="profile"> {...} </div>
                <div class="details"> {...} </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Second way is

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    renderUser = () => (<div class="user"> {... } </div>) 
    renderProfile = () => (<div class="profile"> {...} </div>)
    renderDetails = () => (<div class="details"> {...} </div>)
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderUser()}
                {this.renderProfile()}
                {this.renderDetails()}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: You could write `renderUser = <div>...</div>` as well.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a borderline off-topic because you are asking which solution is more readable. Readability is a matter of opinion and personal preference, and doesn't have a *practical* answer. I guess you should use whatever *you* or *your team* finds more readable. Remember that you don't need to break everything out into functions or include everything inside render(); instead, use a combination of the two to a degree that you find helpful.

In terms of performance however, both solutions would perform pretty much equally well. Any difference would be negligible.

Comment: Could the downvoter please give a reason? I'd gladly improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think both the ways are fine. But the second one is better as it is modular and is easy to

- Read and Understand
- Debug

Answer (score 0):

I generally like to split the html into smaller parts and return them from functions. I.e. your second approach.

This makes your render() smaller. The component is easy to understand, clean and little more helpful for debugging.